# How to resilve BUG INTEGER mapping issue in Elasticsearch using Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I have to index some data, one row of which is having values:

```
'c_22': {
            'raw': '53095200303310000118800091005',
            'integer': 53095200303309998490927497216
        },
```

This is one of the key value pairs that are going to be indexed as a doc in Elasticsearch. Although, Python3 is able to take this as an integer but indexing it in Elasticsearch raises an error:

```
'error': {
        'caused_by': {
            'type': 'illegal_state_exception',
            'reason': 'No matching token for number_type [BIG_INTEGER]'
        },
        'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception',
        'reason': 'failed to parse'
    },
    '_index': '8ca178b8cc4dd678147409af92029685',
    '_id': 'b4505cd90c5e6c47c38889c5722ff495',
    'status': 400
}
```

Note: the value posted above is my estimation of the root cause of this error. The complete row printed out by the debugger is [here](https://pastebin.com/H2NvDc5b)

Comment: Share index mapping.

Answer (score 1):

I got it right with the following way:

```
if _datatype == "number":
   column_parsed_value *= 1.0 #in order to avoid biginteger issue in es.
```

This is a standard way of solving bigint issues; Python will be alright but ES won't.